# How to add functions and variables to a previously instantiated object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using the [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) in TypeScript. After drawing a polygon shape using the API, a `google.maps.Polygon` object is created under the hood and returned via a callback. I'd like to add some functions and variables to that object.

**What is the modern and correct way to add additional functionality and variables to an already instantiated object in TypeScript, one that provides some kind of type information?**

I want to add the following methods to `google.maps.Polygon`

```
interface Polygon {
        setId(id : number);
        getId(): number;
        getShapeType(): Model.ShapeType;
        setShapeType(shapetype: Model.ShapeType);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the module augmentation technique provided by TypeScript. Here's a simple example (from the official [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)):

```
// map.ts
import { Observable } from "./observable";
declare module "./observable" {
    interface Observable<T> {
        map<U>(f: (x: T) => U): Observable<U>;
    }
}
Observable.prototype.map = function (f) {
    // ... another exercise for the reader
}


// consumer.ts
import { Observable } from "./observable";
import "./map";
let o: Observable<number>;
o.map(x => x.toFixed());
```

Comment: Would be nice to have this answer been tailored to the actual question.